# Create deduplicated string from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-server-2017

We have an HR-system where people are placed in up to 7 different organizational levels. Each level is presented in its own column in the database (which is running on MS-SQL 2017)
I would like to create an organizational string, showing the persons place in the organization. But the HR system is repeating value the columns with the previous value in order to fill all columns, so the string is full of duplicates if I just combine the values with a simple function like this is not very useful for the consumer of the string:

`SELECT [OrgLvl1] + ';' + [OrgLvl2] + ';' + [OrgLvl3] + ';' + [OrgLvl4] + ';' + [OrgLvl5] + ';' + [OrgLvl6] + ';' + [OrgLvl7] as 'OrgString'`

Sample of the data might look like this:

```
    |-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
    | OrgLvl1   | OrgLvl2   | OrgLvl3   | OrgLvl4   | OrgLvl5   | OrgLvl6   | OrgLvl7   |
    |-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
    | 1stLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 5thLevel  | 6thLevel  | 7thLevel  |
    | 1stLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 4thLevel  | 5thLevel  | 6thLevel  | 6thLevel  |
    | 1stLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 2ndLevel  | 4thLevel  | 5thLevel  | 6thLevel  | 7thLevel  |
    |-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
```

The result I get is

```
   1stLevel;2ndLevel;2ndLevel;2ndLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel;7thLevel
   1stLevel;2ndLevel;2ndLevel;4thLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel;6thLevel
   1stLevel;2ndLevel;2ndLevel;4thLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel;7thLevel
```

And my desired result would look like this:

```
    1stLevel;2ndLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel;7thLevel
    1stLevel;2ndLevel;4thLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel
    1stLevel;2ndLevel;4thLevel;5thLevel;6thLevel;7thLevel
```

So I'm looking for some method to look at the previous value in the string and eliminate any duplicates.

Update: I used this:

```
IIF([OrgLvl2] != [OrgLvl1], [OrgLvl2] + ';', '') +
IIF([OrgLvl3] != [OrgLvl2], [OrgLvl3] + ';', '') +
IIF([OrgLvl4] != [OrgLvl3], [OrgLvl4] + ';', '') +
IIF([OrgLvl5] != [OrgLvl4], [OrgLvl5] + ';', '') +
IIF([OrgLvl6] != [OrgLvl5], [OrgLvl6] + ';', '') +
IIF([OrgLvl7] != [OrgLvl6], [OrgLvl7] + ';', '') AS 'OrgString'
```

Comment: Of course, my bad. I updated the info, it's running on MS-SQL 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution using `IIF` operator.

```
SELECT 
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl1, 1) = 1, OrgLvl1 + '; ', '') + 
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl2, 1) = 2, OrgLvl2 + '; ', '') +
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl3, 1) = 3, OrgLvl3 + '; ', '') +
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl4, 1) = 4, OrgLvl4 + '; ', '') +
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl5, 1) = 5, OrgLvl5 + '; ', '') +
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl6, 1) = 6, OrgLvl6 + '; ', '') +
    IIF(LEFT(OrgLvl7, 1) = 7, OrgLvl7 + '; ', '') AS 'OrgString'
FROM tableName
```

Demo on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96721fae3d65450effa31562fc13530c)

Comment: Thank you! That's the tip I needed. With a bit of modification I got it the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

to look at the previous, you can do :-

```
OrgLvl1 + ';' +
IIF(OrgLvl2 <> OrgLvl1, OrgLvl2 + ';', '') +
IIF(OrgLvl3 <> OrgLvl2, OrgLvl3 + ';', '') +
IIF(OrgLvl4 <> OrgLvl3, OrgLvl4 + ';', '') + 
IIF(OrgLvl5 <> OrgLvl4, OrgLvl5 + ';', '') +
IIF(OrgLvl6 <> OrgLvl5, OrgLvl6 + ';', '') +
IIF(OrgLvl7 <> OrgLvl6, OrgLvl7 + ';', '') 
AS 'OrgString'
```